# Función de confirmación con SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

Este `alert` debe aparecer cuando oprimo un botón para borrar una fila dentro de una tabla dinámica.

Ya había funcionado si hacía la eliminación sin el `alert`,pero al modificarlo no funciona.

Este es el código:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.borrar', function (event) {
    swal({
        title: "¿Estás seguro?",
        text: "Estás por borrar un proyecto, este no se podrá recuperar más adelante.",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Continuar",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }, 
        function (isConfirm) {
            if(isConfirm){
                swal({
                    title: "Eliminado",
                    text: "Eliminaste el registro del proyecto.",
                    type: "success"
                }, function(){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            });
            }
            else{
                swal("No se ha eliminado.","El registro NO ha sido eliminado.","error");
                delay(2000);
            }
        });

});
```

Otra cosa más, el delay que pongo en el `else` es porque el `alert` se cerraba casi al instante de poner cancelar.

**¡Muchas gracias!**

Comment: Y que es lo que no te da ? Que mensaje de error te arroja?

Comment: ¿Y cuál seria la pregunta?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez No aparece un error, de hecho sale la 'pantalla' del alert que confirma la eliminación, pero mantiene la fila en la tabla.

Comment: @M.Gress La duda es el como hacer que funcione de nuevo el código con el Alert de confirmación, porque con el código de "event.preventDefault(); $(this).closest('tr').remove();" elimina correctamente.

Comment: tienes que agregar esta linea `$(this).closest('tr').remove();` antes de esta `event.preventDefault();` incluso puedes hasta quitar esta linea `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no estoy mal, si se ejecuta `$(this)` dentro de las funciones que devuelve `swal` éste ya no haría referencia al elemento inicial que activó el evento, por lo cual deberías capturar antes el elemento y llamarlo desde la variable en que fue guardado, espero ser claro con esta explicación

```
$(document).on('click', '.borrar', function (event) {
    var elemento = $(this);

    swal({
        title: "¿Estás seguro?",
        text: "Estás por borrar un proyecto, este no se podrá recuperar más adelante.",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Continuar",
        closeOnConfirm: false
        },
        function (isConfirm) {
            if(isConfirm){
                $(elemento).closest('tr').remove();

                swal({
                    title: "Eliminado",
                    text: "Eliminaste el registro del proyecto.",
                    type: "success"
                });
            }else{
                swal("No se ha eliminado.","El registro NO ha sido eliminado.","error");
                delay(2000);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: ¡Funciona perfecto! Muchas gracias por la ayuda, buen día.